# Need a way to put all the inputs into a text area field?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a number guessing game that randomly assigns a number and has you guess the number until you get it and it lets you know whether you need to go higher or lower.

What I am having trouble with is making a textarea that takes each guess along with the guess count and outputs them line by line until the game is won. I've tried a few things that result in the textarea clearing every guess and only displaying the most recent guess.

This is the main code

```
<?php
    require('functions.php');

    $message_for_user = "I've picked a random number between " .
                        RANDOM_NUMBER_MINIMUM . " and " .
                        RANDOM_NUMBER_MAXIMUM . ". Can you guess it?";

    $user_has_guessed_correctly = user_guessed_correctly();

    if (user_submitted_a_guess()) {
        increase_the_user_guess_count();

        if ($user_has_guessed_correctly) {
            $message_for_user = "You got it! It took you " . user_guess_count() . " attempts. Guess again?";
        } else if (user_has_guessed_too_high()) {
            $message_for_user = "Sorry, guess again but lower.";
        } else if (user_has_guessed_too_low()) {
            $message_for_user = "Sorry, guess again but higher.";
        }
    }

    if (secret_number_has_not_yet_been_set() || user_has_requested_a_reset() || $user_has_guessed_correctly) {
        reset_secret_number();
        reset_user_guess_count();
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Guessing Game</h1>
    <p><?= $message_for_user ?></p>

    <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="user_guess">Your Guess</label>
        <input id="user_guess" name="user_guess">
        <input type="submit" name="guess" value="Guess">
        <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="20">

        </textarea>
    </form>
<br>
   <style>
 button{
        padding:5px;
        background-color: solid powderblue;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 100px;
        height:30px;
        margin: auto
}
</style>
    <button onClick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is all my functions

```
<?php
    session_start();

    define("RANDOM_NUMBER_MAXIMUM", 1000);
    define("RANDOM_NUMBER_MINIMUM", 1);

    function user_submitted_a_guess() {
        return isset($_POST['guess']);
    }

    function user_guessed_correctly() {
        return user_guess() == secret_number();
    }

    function user_has_guessed_too_high() {
        return user_guess() > secret_number();
    }

    function user_has_guessed_too_low() {
        return user_guess() < secret_number();
    }

    function user_has_requested_a_reset() {
        return isset($_POST['reset']);
    }

    function fetch($hash, $key) {
            if (isset($hash[$key])) {
                    return $hash[$key];
            }
            else {
                    return false;
            }
    }

    function user_guess() {
        return fetch($_POST, 'user_guess');
    }

    function secret_number() {
        return fetch($_SESSION, 'secret_number');
    }

    function secret_number_has_not_yet_been_set() {
        return !isset($_SESSION['secret_number']);
    }

    function reset_secret_number() {
        $_SESSION['secret_number'] = rand(RANDOM_NUMBER_MINIMUM, RANDOM_NUMBER_MAXIMUM);
    }

    function reset_user_guess_count() {
        $_SESSION['guess_count'] = 0;
    }

    function increase_the_user_guess_count() {
        $_SESSION['guess_count']++;
    }

    function user_guess_count() {
        return fetch($_SESSION, 'guess_count');
    }
?>
```

I kind of got the idea going with the guess counter, but translating that to the textarea with the actual guesses for me always seems to fail.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `textarea` has no `id` or `name` attached to it. If you give it a name you will be able to access it in PHP. Then within the HTML you can output whatever you want by doing `<?= $name ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store all guesses from user to print them. I modified your code a bit: replace `$_SESSION ['guess_count']` with `$_SESSION ['guesses']` - an array that stores all user guesses and added some necessary functions.

Check them out below:

**index.php**

```php
<?php
require('functions.php');

$message_for_user = "I've picked a random number between " .
  RANDOM_NUMBER_MINIMUM . " and " .
  RANDOM_NUMBER_MAXIMUM . ". Can you guess it?";

$user_has_guessed_correctly = user_guessed_correctly();
if (user_submitted_a_guess()) {
  store_the_user_guesses();

  if ($user_has_guessed_correctly) {
    $message_for_user = "You got it! It took you " . user_guess_count() . " attempts. Guess again?";
  } else if (user_has_guessed_too_high()) {
    $message_for_user = "Sorry, guess again but lower.";
  } else if (user_has_guessed_too_low()) {
    $message_for_user = "Sorry, guess again but higher.";
  }
}

if (secret_number_has_not_yet_been_set() || user_has_requested_a_reset() || $user_has_guessed_correctly) {
  reset_secret_number();
  reset_user_guesses();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Guessing Game</h1>
<p><?= $message_for_user ?></p>

<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="user_guess">Your Guess</label>
  <input id="user_guess" name="user_guess">
  <input type="submit" name="guess" value="Guess">
  <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
  <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="guest_list"><?= user_guess_list() ?></textarea>
</form>
<br>
<style>
  button{
    padding:5px;
    background-color: solid powderblue;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
    height:30px;
    margin: auto
  }
</style>
<button onClick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();

define("RANDOM_NUMBER_MAXIMUM", 1000);
define("RANDOM_NUMBER_MINIMUM", 1);

function user_submitted_a_guess() {
  return isset($_POST['guess']);
}

function user_guessed_correctly() {
  return user_guess() == secret_number();
}

function user_has_guessed_too_high() {
  return user_guess() > secret_number();
}

function user_has_guessed_too_low() {
  return user_guess() < secret_number();
}

function user_has_requested_a_reset() {
  return isset($_POST['reset']);
}

function fetch($hash, $key) {
  if (isset($hash[$key])) {
    return $hash[$key];
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

function user_guess() {
  return fetch($_POST, 'user_guess');
}

function secret_number() {
  return fetch($_SESSION, 'secret_number');
}

function secret_number_has_not_yet_been_set() {
  return !isset($_SESSION['secret_number']);
}

function reset_secret_number() {
  $_SESSION['secret_number'] = rand(RANDOM_NUMBER_MINIMUM, RANDOM_NUMBER_MAXIMUM);
}

function reset_user_guesses() {
  $_SESSION['guesses'] = [];
}

function store_the_user_guesses() {
  $_SESSION['guesses'][] = user_guess();
}

function user_guess_count() {
  return isset($_SESSION['guesses']) ? count($_SESSION['guesses']) : false;
}

function user_guess_list() {
  if (empty($_SESSION['guesses'])) {
    return null;
  }
  $res = '';
  foreach ($_SESSION['guesses'] as $key => $guess) {
    $res .= ($key + 1) . ': ' . $guess . "\n";
  }
  return $res;
}
?>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your user guesses in a session variable (which will be reset each session e.g. when you close your browser tab). Also place your text inside the textarea opening and closing tags. Here's the code (just tweak index.php, no need to modify functions.php):

```
<?php
    require('functions.php');

    $_SESSION["a"] = $_SESSION["a"] . "User guess : " . + $_POST['user_guess'] . "  " . "Guess count : " . + user_guess_count() . "\n";

    $message_for_user = "I've picked a random number between " .
                        RANDOM_NUMBER_MINIMUM . " and " .
                        RANDOM_NUMBER_MAXIMUM . ". Can you guess it?";

    $user_has_guessed_correctly = user_guessed_correctly();

    if (user_submitted_a_guess()) {
        increase_the_user_guess_count();

        if ($user_has_guessed_correctly) {
            $message_for_user = "You got it! It took you " . user_guess_count() . " attempts. Guess again?";
        } else if (user_has_guessed_too_high()) {
            $message_for_user = "Sorry, guess again but lower.";
        } else if (user_has_guessed_too_low()) {
            $message_for_user = "Sorry, guess again but higher.";
        }
    }

    if (secret_number_has_not_yet_been_set() || user_has_requested_a_reset() || $user_has_guessed_correctly) {
        reset_secret_number();
        reset_user_guess_count();
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Guessing Game</h1>
    <p><?= $message_for_user ?></p>

    <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="user_guess">Your Guess</label>
        <input id="user_guess" name="user_guess">
        <input type="submit" name="guess" value="Guess">
        <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">

<textarea rows="8" cols="40">
<?= $_SESSION["a"] ?>
</textarea>

</form>

<br>

   <style>
 button{
        padding:5px;
        background-color: solid powderblue;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 100px;
        height:30px;
        margin: auto
}
</style>
    <button onClick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

Result :

[image]